# How to discover the id, and await an existing Promise?

Tags: javascript, synchronization

The simplest solution is perhaps some [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) after adding some  [promise pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or reusing... 
I not see how to *reuse* the Promise, that  I suppose it already exists, into the  method   `csv-parse.readFileSync()`, or the method `parse()`, illustrated below.

Another solution is to add more promises and some  ***async/await***: the whole LOAD block can be a function... But I also not see where put the awaits.

```
'use strict';
const fs     = require('fs')
const path   = require('path')

// CONFIGS:
const cf_cover_dataset = '../data/cover.csv'
var COVER = null;

// LOAD external configs:
var COVER_file = path.resolve(__dirname, cf_cover_dataset);
if (path.extname(cf_cover_dataset)=='.csv') {
  const parse  = require('csv-parse') // npm i csv-parse  (not parse"r")
  let raw = []
  parse(fs.readFileSync( COVER_file ), {
    trim: true,
    skip_empty_lines: true
  })
  .on('readable', function(){
    let record
    while (record = this.read()){
      raw.push(record)  ; console.log('.')}
  })
  .on('error', function(err){ console.error(err.message) })
  .on('end', function(){

     // I NEED TO WAY THE END HERE, HOW TO?

    COVER = f(raw);
    console.log("1. cover from CSV");
  });
} else {
  COVER = JSON.parse(COVER_file)  // ... and WAY here
  console.log("1. cover from JSON");
}

console.log("2. END!!");
```

The result is

```
   2. END!!
   1. cover from JSON
```

How to get step2 after step1?

Answer (score 1):

This is more one workaround, not a real solution using e.g. `await`. 
(please edit this answer, it is a Wiki,  you can correct my asumptions, my English, or add clues and links)

---

Seems that the only solution is the ugly naive solution, encapsulating all software in a `main()`  function:

```
if (path.extname(cf_cover_dataset)=='.csv') {
  ...
  parse(fs.readFileSync( COVER_file ), {
    ...
  })
  .on('readable', function(){
    ...
  })
  .on('error', function(err){ ... })
  .on('end', function(){
    COVER = f(raw);
    console.log("1. cover from CSV");
    main();
  });
} else {
  COVER = JSON.parse(COVER_file)  // ... and WAY here
  console.log("1. cover from JSON");
  main();
}

function main() {  // step2, ugly but run in sequence 
   console.log("2. END!!");
}
```

---

What I really need is the  *non-documented name of the promises* to be easy to await all. See [the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54171929/287948)

Answer (score 0):

csv-parse offers a sync API according to https://csv.js.org/parse/api/#sync-api

I guess using this works around the whole promise/callback hassle you want to avoid

Comment: Hum... It is a workaround... Ok, I try. Problem when replaced `require('csv-parse')`  by `require('csv-parse/lib/sync')`: (node:11788) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: parse(...).on is not a function
(node:11788) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Maybe it's a misunderstanding. I thought you wanted the code to be synchronous, so I came up with this.
If you want to keep it asynchronously, you have to ensure that the "2. END!!" statements are only called if the if/else blocks are done.
Thus I recommend wrapping it all in a function, that returns a Promise, that you can handle. If you end up in the else-clause, just do Promise.resolve(), so the method returns, like so `return Promise.resolve(COVER);`

Answer (score 0):

you are reading file in sync mode but you are parsing in async mode. To use the parser in sync mode, like previously explained, you must require `csv-parse/lib/sync` to use the [CSV parse sync API](https://csv.js.org/parse/api/#sync-api).

See my answer on[GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170238/how-to-wait-a-readfilesync) which include an example.