# How to list all promisses

Tags: javascript, promise

I am reading [Promise.all() guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) but not seems what I need, I need to do something as `console.log(Promise.LIST_OF_ALL_CREATED)` and see a list (array or object) of all promises. I  not know the promise IDs or variable names.

I need for debug list... And also for example, `await` all, or some selected ones.

Comment: what do you mean? all the promises created within your application?

Comment: Thanks @quirimmo, yes. I editing.

Comment: and what do you want to see? I mean, if I create a promise like `new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true))`... what do you expect to see? I mean, counting the number of promises is one thing, but "see the promises" what does it mean?

Comment: @quirimmo, ok, edited again.

Comment: Please tell us what the REAL problem is that you're trying to solve and maybe we can help with that.  Listing all promises is not the actual problem.  That's apparently some scheme you're trying to use to solve the actual problem.  Please describe the actual problem.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, you can see a good example at https://stackoverflow.com/q/54170238/287948

Comment: @PeterKrauss I don't see how that is related to finding all promises in an application

Comment: @PeterKrauss if you're using Node, there is the [Aysnc Hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) module that will let you tap into the system when various async operations happen. It's not as simple as "list all promises", but it is flexible and powerful.

Comment: That question link doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question.  You still haven't described your actual problem (in your question).  Don't think we can help.  This question will probably get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `Promise.new()` is just a reference to the promise. If you want to list all promises in an application, you need to get a reference to them when they're created.

`Promise.all()` is not related to getting all active promises in an application, it's used for something else.

There is no magical way to get a list of all "in flight" promises in an application. You just need to get the variable references, the same way you would do for any other variable.

Comment: Make sense, you confirming what documentation "seems to say"... Well, there are no *debug tool*  or NodeJS pack to list promises?  Look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54170238/287948), can I discover the name of the used promises, to `await` them?

Comment: Nothing in the question you linked to uses promises

Comment: Thanks Andy.  Ok, thats all.